# OpenCV - How to make the letters in these images clear to be readable by Tesseract?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I'm trying to convert the numbers (coordinates) in these images. They need to be clear to be converted to text with [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).

I have tried several things, but I'm not an image processing expert so most of it hasn't worked very well. Currently, I'm adjusting brightness and contrast, then doing a `blur` and then using `cv2.threshold` to convert it to a binary image. At the end I do an `erode` and `dilate`. But because the letters have opacity the background gets mixed with it and causes wrong readings.

```py
blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(coord_img,(5,5),0)
avg_brightness = cv2.mean(blur_img)[0]
beta = -2*avg_brightness-50
contrast_img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(blur_img, alpha=3.5, beta=beta)
ret, threshold_img = cv2.threshold(contrast_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
erode_img = cv2.erode(threshold_img, np.ones((3,3)), iterations=1)
dilate_img = cv2.dilate(erode_img, np.ones((3,3)), iterations=2)
processed_img = cv2.erode(dilate_img, np.ones((3,3)), iterations=2)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_img, config='--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=" -0123456789"')
```

Examples images:
[image: example image 1]

[image: example image 2]

[image: example image 3]

The expected outcome of the image pre-processing should be something like this:
[image: intended output]

Is there a better way of pre-processing this to remove the background so that only the letters are visible?

Any help and suggestions are welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: "I have tried several things"  please post what you have tried, your results and then maybe someone have some suggestion on how to improve the results. Instead of explaining that you adjust brightness, do a blur and thresholding with morphology you should post that code, so people can run it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thanks! I added the code excerpt for the image pre-processing as requested.

Comment: It does the best that it can, but contrary to what movies show you, there is no magic here.  Even as a human, I could not tell you whether the second line was -0098 or -0093.  And the third line could be "0444 -4928" or "0441 -1928".  You need better source material.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes those examples are quite hard. But for the first example it is quite readable for humans but I can't get it to work with opencv. There should be some way of doing it but I just don't know how.

Comment: It's more work, but if you always have the same font and you can locate the digits, you could program a neural net to recognize your specific digits.  A net should be able to pick the pattern even with an ugly background.